# Jupyter notebook picks older version of numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am  using `python 2.7.6` and trying to import pandas but Jupyter notebook gives me following

> error--
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import pandas
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/**init**.py in
>   ()
>        21 
>        22 # numpy compat
>   ---> 23 from pandas.compat.numpy import *
>        24 
>        25 try:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/**init**.py
>   in ()
>        22                       'your numpy version is {0}.\n'
>        23                       'Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use '
>   ---> 24                       'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
>        25 
>        26
>
> ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0
>   your numpy version is 1.8.2. Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use
>   this pandas version

while I have numpy 1.14.1

```
$ pip freeze
numpy==1.14.1
pandas==0.22.0
pip-magic==0.2.3
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2018.3
six==1.11.0
```

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling `numpy` and `pandas` from ubuntu terminal as well as Jupyter's terminal but unable to solve the error, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the jupyter notebook after reinstalling the numpy and pandas library?

Comment: yup but it didnot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying multiple things I was able to resolve it.

The issue here was that `python2.7` had older version of `numpy` i.e. `1.8.2` as the error in the question reports.

In python shell I found the path of numpy in use as follow.

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

the output was this path

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
```

went to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages  and deleted numpy using

```
sudo rm -r numpy
```

then staying in `dist-packages` directory I installed `numpy 1.14.1` simply with `pip`.

```
sudo pip install numpy==1.14.1
```

this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I could imagine that you have different versions of Python on your computer. In the Jupyter Notebook try running

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

This will show you which Python interpreter is used

EDIT:

You can install a new kernel for `jupyter` that uses the correct Python interpreter. First get a list of the existing kernels that you have:
Type `jupyter kernelspec list`. If the wanted interpreter is not there you will have to install it. To do so use `python -m ipykernel install --name <Kernelname> --display-name <Displayname>` Note that the python interpreter you are using to run this command must be the python interpreter that you want to be used by the kernel. 
Now you are set up!
Start a new notebook and you will find that you can choose this new kernel

Comment: it outputs '/usr/bin/python', now i have python , python2, python2.7, python3, python3.4 binaries in same bin folder. how do i make sure that it uses right binary?

Comment: Since the ouput is  '/usr/bin/python' I would say the 'python' interpreter is used.

Comment: how can i tell my system to use python2.7 interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make sure that you use the right version or `jupyter` is the `-m` option of `python`:

> `-m mod` : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

If this shows NumPy 1.14:

```
python -m pip freeze
```

starting `jupyter` like this should also give you the same version:

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

you can find what versions of `python` are on your system and in what order they are searched with:

```
which -a python
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you `rm -rf` the numpy library and install the version he is asking you too.

```
sudo pip install numpy==1.14.1
```